# How to see stack trace when app is crashed by C/C++ exception?

Tags: debugging, apportable

Currently, Apportable doesn't show any stack trace on crash by C/C++ exception.

How can I make it to print stack-trace when it is crashed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apportable debug` to attach a gdb debugger to the app. Then use the command `continue` to get to the crash; `backtrace` to see the trace; `up`, `down`, and `frame {number}` to navigate through the trace; and `print {expression}` to examine state.

More information in the [docs page](http://docs.apportable.com/debugging.html#attaching-a-debugger).

For C++ exceptions in particular, you will get a confusing stack trace. We'll investigate adding better debugger support for these. In the meantime you could set a breakpoint on the throw(break __cxa_throw).

Comment: I also wish to have a way to set a breakpoint with `apportable debug` command line.

Comment: You can add breakpoints (or any gdb commands) to a $HOME/.gdbinit file.  Also gdb command line history (with up arrow) is configured into the apportable gdb setup